# How to request json from different domain using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, ecmascript-6

I am trying to load a json file cross domain, from http://xinruima.me/game/themes.json

I tried to write this in AngularJs for ES6:

```
  getThemesOptions() {
    const url = `http://xinruima.me/game/themes.json`;
    return this.$http.jsonp(url)
      .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

It give me error: [image]

And then I found this online: http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/a4Rc2/114/ 
It's an example to call a public api using the same syntax I wrote, it works.
[image]

But when I change the url to my url, it gives the error as I shown above:

I tested my json file and it's valid.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `http://xinruima.me/game/themes.json` URL is not a `JSONP` response, but a regular `JSON`.

The error is the browser trying to parse your JSON response as Javascript. Which does not happen to your fiddle requst, as the url `http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` is a valid JSONP response.

You could use `$http.get` instead of `$http.jsonp`

```
getThemesOptions() {
    const url = `http://xinruima.me/game/themes.json`;
    return this.$http.get(url)
      .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

But the request to `http://xinruima.me/game/themes.json` does not allow cross-domain requests so you will still have an error. On Chrome, for example, you can [disable the cross-domain security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) but this would be good just while in development and if you don't have control over the server on xinruima.me you won't be able to overcome this security limitation.

EDIT:

As `JSONP` seems not be an option, you can check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for possible ways of overcoming cross-domain errors.

Comment: I do have full control the server of xinruima.me, what should I do to overcome that limitation? Thanks

Comment: You have to add cross-domain headers (`Access-Control-*`) allowing the request from your origin (place/domain where this angular app is hosted) so that the browser knows it is a safe call. Check this MDN _CORS_ article for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS